# Cannot read property of undefined on Ionic even with results showing up

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Can you help me solve this?

I'm getting a list of products from an api and showing up on the app. The thing is, the list appears on the view, on the console, but the system returns an error saying that it cannot read property 'name' of undefined. Can you help me understand this error? I've spent a lot of time trying to figure it out but couldn't find any way that fixed that.

This is me calling the getProducts() from products.ts

```
getProducts(){
    this.products=[];
    var product = localStorage.getItem('productId');

    this.products.getProduct(product).subscribe(res=>{


      for(var i = 0; i<this.ObjectLength(res) ; i++){

        if(res['total']>0){

          if(res['res']!==undefined){

            this.productAvailable = true;
            this.productArr.push({request: res['res'][i]["Name"]})
          }



        }else{
          this.productAvailable=false;
        }

      }

    })
  }
```

on my provider I'm calling the server using:

```
getProduct(product){

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:5500/product/requests', {
      products: product
    })

  }
```

I have console logged it and it works fine, it is printing the list of product names. I just can't find out why it is returning an error.

The items are appearing on the console and on the app but I still get this error.

```
core.js:1350 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (products.ts:53)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:89)
    at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:145)
```

The error points exactly to this line:

```
this.productArr.push({request: res['res'][i]["Name"]})
```

Comment: Try to use `.then` instead of `.subscribe`.

Comment: Should the word `Name` actually need to be in lower case: `name`?

Comment: Tried @StephanStrate but it says `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.`

Comment: Actually not @R.Richards it's coming from the server with this name.

Comment: Do you use Ionic Native HTTP, because this should return a Promise.

Comment: `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';` Is it?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/ I believe your mistake is somewhere in your if clauses, but you can use the promises of Ionic Native HTTP

Comment: I tried to answer your problem, but we are missing some code in the question itself, a model or the response object of course and the function this.ObjectLength function. I have a feeling that function is redundant since you have Object.Keys native JS function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the if condition, you are doing another iteration reaching an undefined index on the array, therefore, having an undefined reference

```
i < this.ObjectLength(res)
```

should be

```
i <= this.ObjectLength(res)
```

a better approach will be to use forEach iteration and then you can reach an undefined cause the array will only iterate the number of object in it.